# Ao clicar em um checkbox o próximo componente aparecer

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Gostaria de saber a melhor forma de começar renderizando esse primeiro objeto e quando clicar no checkbox ele renderizar o próximo, escondendo o anterior e assim por diante.

```
const [expensesData, setExpensesData] = useState([
    {
      position: 0,
      label: 'Descrição',
      show: true,
      value: '',
    },
    {
      position: 1,
      label: 'Valor',
      show: false,
      value: '',
    },
    {
      position: 2,
      label: 'Categoria',
      show: false,
      value: '',
    },
    {
      position: 3,
      label: 'Data',
      show: false,
      value: '',
    },
    {
      position: 4,
      label: 'Pago com',
      show: false,
      value: '',
    },
    {
      position: 5,
      label: 'Repete',
      show: false,
      value: '',
    },
    {
      position: 6,
      label: 'Pago',
      show: false,
      value: '',
    },
  ]);

  const handleShowNextOption = useCallback(
    index => {
      console.log(index);
    },
    [expensesData],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <OptionsContainer>
            {expensesData.map((item, index) => (
              <>
                {item.position === index && item.show && (
                  <OptionItem>
                    <span>{item?.label}</span>
                    <Input name="description" type="text" value={item?.value} />
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      onClick={() => handleShowNextOption(index)}
                    />
                  </OptionItem>
                )}
              </>
            ))}
          </OptionsContainer>
        </Form>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala Yuri!

Você pode manter um estado que represente o objeto/componente aberto, referenciando por um valor único de cada objeto (no seu caso seria o `position`). Quando você marcar um checkbox, você seta no estado a posição do próximo item (cuidado para não setar uma posição que não existe). E no render você pode verificar se o valor desse estado combina com o position do item no array

Outra alternativa, que está bem próximo do que fez é atribuir uma mesma função para todos os `checkbox`, e quando marcado o checkbox, você passa para a função a posição do objeto que está em interação com o usuário, e na função você seta o show desse objeto como false e o show do próximo objeto (position + 1) como true.